# iPhone App rejected because of “non-public API” “ignore”

Tags: ios, nstimer, appstore-approval, runloop

Apple has rejected my app, because it's using a non-public api, i.e. ignore.

I am using XMPPFramework in my app, and in XMPPParser, the following line of codes are used

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

// We can't run the run loop unless it has an associated input source or a timer.
// So we'll just create a timer that will never fire - unless the server runs for 10,000 years.
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:DBL_MAX target:self selector:@selector(ignore:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

// Run the runloop

BOOL allIsWell = YES;
while(!stopped && allIsWell)
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *innerPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    allIsWell = [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                                         beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3600.0]];
    [innerPool release];
}

[pool release];
```

**EDIT:** How can avoid using this ignore selector to get my app approved?

Comment: my question is how can I avoid using this ignore selector, as this is a normal senario for calling run loop

Comment: I resolved this issue by changing the name of the selector (ignore:) and then implemented that selector in my code, with no functionality at all inside it.

    - (void) dummySelector
{
//ignore
}